# requireActivity() and requireContext() in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

What is the purpose of  [`requireActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireActivity()) and [`requireContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#requireContext()) in `Fragment`?

Comment: Can you explain your question more clearly

Answer (score 12):

Because they might be null. In java, you can just call for them. But in Kotlin they are declared as nullable return types. So you have 3 options:

1. You are not sure if it is  null or not:

   ```java
   activity?.let { it -> 
        it.doSomething() //do what you need to do.
   }
   ```
2. You are sure it will not be null so you can call

   ```java
   activity!!.doSomething()
   ```

but it is ugly and unclear. It does not show intention. Have you really expected the activity to be available or this is just a leftover after Java to Kotlin conversion?

3. This is the cleanest option where you are sure it will not be null, but if somehow it is, there will be a specific exception(IllegalStateException) prepared for this and it will be thrown and not generic NullPointerException.

   ```java
    requireActivity().doSomething() // throws IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to an activity.")
    requireContext().doSomething()  // throws IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.")
   ```

Comment: I don't see the difference between `requireActivity().` and `!!.` as they both throw exceptions and you have to chase them down as a programmer.  `!!.` looks a LOT less ugly to me.  And it's already built into kotlin.

Comment: @SMBiggs Yeah, I think `requireActivity.` is just a sneaky `!!.`.

Answer (score 6):

Check the official Android Source code documentation. Those methods return activity/context with a null check.

**requireActivity()**

```
public final FragmentActivity requireActivity() {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to an activity.");
        }
        return activity;
    }
```

**requireContext()**

```
public final Context requireContext() {
        Context context = getContext();
        if (context == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
        }
        return context;
    }
```

Comment: When to use `requireActivity` vs `requireContext`?

Comment: replying to @IgorGanapolsky, it depends on what's needed - remember that an Activity carries a lot more "baggage" than a Context, so if the parameter only needs a Context, use `requireContext`, only use `requireActivity` if you NEED the Activity...

edit, sorry for the comment 9 months after the question